# Cannot overload the >> operator with istream c++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the >> operator to use it like cin with my class. Here is the code:

```
class Base {
public:
    int mx;
    Base() {}
    Base(int x) : mx(x) {}
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Base &);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Base &);

};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &in, Base &object) {
    in >> object.mx;
    return in;
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Base &object) {
    out << object.mx;
    return out;
}

int main() {

    Base test();
    std::cin >> test;
    std::cout << test;
    system("PAUSE");


    return 0;

}
```

When I try to compile I get "error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Base (__cdecl *)(void)' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
and Intellisense says no operator '>>' matches these operands.

the ostream version doesn't seem to have any problem.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has **two** problems.

1) This declares a function instead of defining variable:

```
Base test();
```

Make that:

```
Base test;
```

2) You need to take a reference for the second parameter of `operator>>`:

```
std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &in, Base& object)
```

Also, your code does not really work for `operator<<`, at least it won't do what you are expecting it to do unless you fix problem 1) from above.

Comment: @DouglasEdward No problem. I see you edited the Q, so problem 2) was just a typo in the Q and not your code and 1) was the real problem? Happens to anyone sooner or later :)

Answer (score 1):

the way you are creating the object is wrong , should use as :
`Base test;`